# TypeScript and Jest - auto creation of full mocks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

I am working with NestJS and to make testing easier I am trying to create something like Moq in .NET which gives complete mock based on the class with all methods mocked etc.
To clarify: when I have `ClassA` with methods `testA` and `testB`, I want my function to return an object which has these methods mocked with `jest.fn()` without having to create these objects every time by the hand.

I can get it working with pure JS without any issues:

```
export function getMockedClass<T>(classDef: T): MyAutoMock<T> {
  const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classDef);
  const constructorIndex = methods.findIndex((m) => 'constructor');
  if (constructorIndex >= 0) {
    methods.slice(constructorIndex, 1);
  }
  const mock: any = {};
  methods.forEach((methodName) => {
    mock[methodName] = jest.fn();
  });
  return mock;
}
```

However I am struggling to create type for `MyAutoMock` to get it accepted by TS as proper instance of the given class. Replacing `MyAutoMock<T>` with just `:T` obviously does not  work.

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: FYI: Jest can already mock whole classes out of the box. [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks)

Comment: Does not work with named exports and anyway it is not typing it properly